# ¿Cómo eliminar máscara antes de submit?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mask-plugin

Tengo un form en Asp.Net MVC como este:

```
@model Project.ViewModels.Stations.StationViewModel

<form asp-controller="Stations" asp-action="Create" asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData[" ReturnUrl"]" method="post" class="needs-validation" role="form" novalidate>

  ....form inputs
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label asp-for="Rate" class="form-label"></label>
      <input asp-for="Rate" class="form-control" id="currency-mask" required autofocus />
      <div class="invalid-feedback">Rate is required.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary me-1" value="Save Agency" />
</form>
```

Como pueden ver, utilizo `id="currency-format"`, uso [IMask](https://imask.js.org/) para eso, mi código *javascript* se ve de la siguiente manera:

```
<script src="~/assets/libs/imask/imask.min.js"></script>

<script>
    const currencyMask = IMask(
        document.getElementById('currency-mask'), {
            mask: [{
                    mask: ''
                },
                {
                    mask: '$ num ',
                    lazy: false,
                    blocks: {
                        num: {
                            mask: Number,
                            scale: 2,
                            thousandsSeparator: ',',
                            padFractionalZeros: true,
                            radix: '.',
                            mapToRadix: ['.'],
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
</script>
```

El formateo funciona correctamente, el problema empieza cuando quiero hacer *submit* al form, el campo devuelve 0.

[image]

Y el *model state* regresa:

> The value '$ 100.21 ' is not valid for Rate.

Mi pregunta es: ¿cómo puedo remover la máscara antes de hacer submit?

**UPDATE**

Trate de utilizar el evento `onclick` en mi input para remover la máscara:

```
 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary me-1" onclick="currencyUnmask()" value="Save Agency" />
```

luego

```js
function currencyUnmask() {
    IMask(document.getElementById('currency-mask')).destroy();
}
```

Pero me tira error en la consola:

> Uncaught Error: mask property should be defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes 2 errores:

1. Estas creando un objeto Mask y lo destruyes, pero tú ya lo tienes creado en const currencyMask = IMask
2. Para que el onclick funcione antes del submit debes poner return

Algo así:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary me-1" onclick=" return currencyUnmask()" value="Save Agency" />

function currencyUnmask() {
   currencyMask.destroy();
   return true;
}
```

Otra cosa que puede funcionar es enlazar el dato a input hidden, mediante el evento oninput

```
<input asp-for="Rate" class="form-control" oninput="valorreal.value =currencyMask.unmaskedValue" id="currency-mask" required autofocus />
<input type="hidden" id="valorreal" asp-for="Rate" />
```

Y al crear el Mask tienes que agregar el valor desde el hidden al otro input con mask, esto en el caso que ya vengan valores (en un crud sería el caso Edit)

```
 let cm = document.getElementById('currency-mask');
 cm.value = document.getElementById('valorreal').value;
 const currencyMask = IMask(
        cm, {
            mask: [{
                    mask
//resto de cosas
```

UPDATE: EJEMPLO

```js
const currencyMask = IMask(
        document.getElementById('currency-mask'), {
            mask: [{
                    mask: ''
                },
                {
                    mask: '$ num ',
                    lazy: false,
                    blocks: {
                        num: {
                            mask: Number,
                            scale: 2,
                            thousandsSeparator: ',',
                            padFractionalZeros: true,
                            radix: '.',
                            mapToRadix: ['.'],
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
        
function ver(){
  console.log("con mascara", document.getElementById("currency-mask").value);
  console.log("sin mascara", document.getElementById("valorreal").value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/imask"></script>

<input class="form-control" onkeyup="valorreal.value =currencyMask.unmaskedValue" id="currency-mask" required autofocus />
<input asp-for="Rate"  type="hidden" id="valorreal" asp-for="Rate" />

<button onclick="ver()">ver valores</button>
```

**3) Opción utilizando el evento complete**

El cual se ejecutando cuando hay cambios en el input con mask

```js
const currencyMask = IMask(
        document.getElementById('currency-mask'), {
            mask: [{
                    mask: ''
                },
                {
                    mask: '$ num ',
                    lazy: false,
                    blocks: {
                        num: {
                            mask: Number,
                            scale: 2,
                            thousandsSeparator: ',',
                            padFractionalZeros: true,
                            radix: '.',
                            mapToRadix: ['.'],
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
currencyMask.on("complete", function () {
valorreal.value =currencyMask.unmaskedValue
 });       
function ver(){
  console.log("con mascara", document.getElementById("currency-mask").value);
  console.log("sin mascara", document.getElementById("valorreal").value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/imask"></script>

<input class="form-control" id="currency-mask" required autofocus />
<input asp-for="Rate"  type="hidden" id="valorreal" asp-for="Rate" />

<button onclick="ver()">ver valores</button>
```

Comment: Estoy tratando la segunda opción pero cuando escribo en el input la consola tira error: Uncaught ReferenceError: currencyMask is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.oninput

Comment: @Demian Al final de mi respuesta puse un ejemplo funcional

Comment: Veo que si funciona, pero mi CRUD sigue tomando el valor con máscara en la propiedad de rate, por lo cual sigue tirando el error de model state en el back: The value '$ 23,032' is not valid for Rate.

Comment: @Demian recuerda que el asp-for="Rate" ahora debe ir en el input hidden

Comment: Funciona excelente!, pero hay un problema al ingresar los decimales, en tu ejemplo: utiliza 20.21, y dale click al botón, no toma el segundo decimal al menos que presiones dos veces el 1

Comment: @Demian Pero un numero menos quien lo va a notar!! Cambia onipunt por onkeyup o onkeypress También sería bueno agregar el evento onpaste con la misma función, por si alguien decide copiar/pegar

Comment: @Demian Añadí una tercera opción, la que creo mejor favor verifícala